# Kairos API - get JSON response

Tags: android, json, image-recognition, face-recognition, api-design

I would like to use Kairos' API for face recognition. It seems a pretty good system, but have no idea, how to catch examples. If I use a string, it is empty after the process. There isn't any example about this in API documentation, nor in its GitHub repo: https://github.com/kairosinc/Kairos-SDK-Android
I try to connect to http://api.kairos.com, but maybe there is a problem with authentication, or should use URL with some parameters added. I cannot found any information about this.

Comment: Did you find the solution??

Comment: @AbdulKawee : Yes, I made an application too.

Answer (score 2):

You might be missing the proper APP_ID and APP_KEY headers. [Check out this answered solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48751935/1133003) using a Curl example.