# API webservice testing with Postman

Tags: web-services, rest, postman, api-design

I installed `Postman` inside Chrome to test [Kairos](https://www.kairos.com/docs/api/#face-recognition) API webservice. I have set following fields:
[image]

I get error message, but regarding to API documentation it should be working in this format.

> Authentication parameters missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Kairos' website it says:

> Requests must be authenticated with your API key. ***This must be sent as an HTTP header.***

So click the "Add token to the header" radio button under "Previously Used" instead of the "Add token to the url" button, and it should work!

Answer (score 1):

The API is prompting for your developer APP ID and APP KEY. You are missing these headers in your requests.

Here's an example via Curl:

```
curl -s -X POST http://api.kairos.com/detect \
-H "content-type: application/json" \
-H "app_id: xxxxxx" \
-H "app_key: xxxxxx"  \
-d '{ "image": "http://media.kairos.com/test1.jpg" }'
```

Make sure to replace the `xxxxxx` strings with your developer APP_ID and APP_KEY.

You can [register for a free developer account](https://developer.kairos.com/signup) and you can browse the [API documentation here](https://kairos.com/docs/api/).